Export/Import the state of a Bucket in bucket-4j
I am using bucket-4j to limit the number of times a specific request can be made by each user within multiple time windows (one day, one week, and one month). For each user, I create a Bucket and maintain it appropriately in memory.
Now, I need to export (serialize) the state of the Bucket to a suitable format (like JSON) and store this state in a database so that I can later retrieve it and recreate the Bucket.
I do not want to use the existing integrations like jdbc-integration.
Do the Buckets in bucket-4j support such functionality?

Since you do not plan to use distributed facilities, it is legal to always cast bucket to LocalBucket https://github.com/bucket4j/bucket4j/blob/8.13/bucket4j-core/src/main/java/io/github/bucket4j/local/LocalBucket.java
LocalBucket provides all neccesary functionality for serialization and desiralization from/to both binary form and JSON compatible HashMap.
Can I ask you what database do you plan to use?

Thanks. Regarding your question, the type of database does not matter for our architecture. The main concern is to store this record for each user. Currently, we are using Oracle.
The toBinarySnapshot and fromBinarySnapshot methods seem to be more optimized and backward-compatible. So, if we upgrade the bucket-4j version in the future, we should not worry about deserializing old binaries. Is that correct?

Yes. Serializationin bucket4j is designed to be backward compatible. Any new version of library is able to read binary that generated by previos version.
